# MFC Container based application

Tags: mfc

I have a Doc-View architecture based project completely ready. But now i want to convert it in container based application to provide OLE support to existing project.
 if anyone know how to convert, please reply as soon as possible. i just need a way without copy paste of existing code to new container based application- i tried - not worked even after settings change.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good worked example of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177529.aspx).  Basically all your CDocument derived classes must be now be derived from COLEDocument, and you need some extra code in your WinApp.InitInstance.

If you post the code that you tried, you may get a more detailed response as to what is going wrong.